# How can I get only data from a response and show it into a blade template in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, api, rest, get

Controller code

```
 public function add_employee(){

    $covid_statuses = Http::get("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/covid/status");


     $covid_statuses =  json_decode($covid_statuses['data'],200);
    //  $covid_statuses =  json_encode($covid_statuses['data'],200);

     return view('admin.hr.os.employee.add_employee',compact('covid_statuses'));


    // return view('admin.hr.os.employee.add_employee',[
    //     'covid_statuses' => $covid_statuses,
    //     // 'covid_statuses' => json_decode($covid_statuses['data']),
    // ]);

}
```

The main respone is like `{"data":[{"id":1,"name":"1st dose completed"},{"id":2,"name":"2nd dose completed"}],"success":true,"status":200}`

When I decode only data, and pass into blade and in blade I use to debug like  `@foreach($covid_statuses as $covid_status) {{$covid_status}} @endforeach`

but I got

> json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

When I use encode then I got

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

How Can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could use array_walk for that purpose. Try:

```
    $covid_statuses = array_walk($covid_statuses['data'], function(&$item, &$id) { 
        $item = $item['name'];
        $id = $item['id'];
});
```

Like this, the array will only contain the names of the covid cases, by it will have the same id as in the original request

Comment: Groger then it show "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: F:\Arafat\projects\my-projects\mis-frontend\resources\views\admin\hr\os\employee\add_employee.blade.php)" this message

Comment: could you dd the covid statuses variable in the controller? :)

Comment: here is the response when use dd. array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "1st dose completed"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "2nd dose completed"
  ]
]

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if it worked

Comment: same issue and now dd looks like array:2 [▼
  "cookies" => []
  "transferStats" => []
]

Comment: sorry, I forget to add the ['data'] index. I updated the answer, could you try it again?

Comment: it also same issue. and dd is like array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "1st dose completed"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "2nd dose completed"
  ]
]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241679/discussion-between-matyas-groger-and-arafat-rahman).

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks for your help! Actually the main thing is  $covid_statuses = $covid_statuses['data'];  this is an array, not an object. So I should use into the foreach $item['name']   or $item['id'].                                                                                                             And if I use json_decode(json_encode($covid_statuses['data']), false), then it converts into an object. And at this time I should use foreach $item->name  or $item->id. @Matyas Thanks for you help!

Comment: I am glad you solved it